# Type Conversion and compile time constant

Tags: java, casting

```
byte b=5;
Integer i=(int)b;//b cast to int and int wrapped into Integer
Integer k=(byte)b;//compilation error, cannot convert from byte to Integer
Integer z=(byte)5;//compiles
```

My question is why `Integer z=(byte)5` compiles while `Integer k=(byte)b` does not? For that matter `Integer z1 = (byte)5L` and `Integer z2 = (byte)5.3F` also compile. Is it because I am attempting to cast a compile time constant and the cast has no effect on it?

Comment: I get a compile error for both the `(byte) b` line and the `(byte) 5` line: both `incompatible types
found   : byte
required: java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: I also get the same compiler error for `Integer z1 = (byte) 5L;` and for `Integer z2 = (byte) 5.3F;`, again: `incompatible types
found   : byte
required: java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: It probably matters what version of the JDK you are using.

Comment: I think its simple behavior of lexical analysis during compilation. In first and third, it finds the reference of `int` and assumes OK but it doesn't find any reference in second hence complains. If you do `Integer k= (int)(byte)b;`, should also work.

Comment: @BaileyS, I get the same errors in 1.4/1.5/1.6/1.7.

Comment: @rgettman It makes you wonder what crazy JDK he is using!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the assignment

`Integer z=(byte)5`

uses a literal value, it is translated immediately by the compiler to

```
Integer z = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

The compiler is not smart enough to reference variables as in the case:

```
Integer k= (byte)b;
```